# pulp cbc.exe error at line

Tags: pulp, pulpcore

When I use solverstudio with pulp and default cbc solver, I see such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "<string>",line188, in <module>
File "...\PulP\src\pulp\pulp.py",line1641,in solver
File "...\PulP\src\pulp\solvers.py",line1303,inactualSolve
File "...\PulP\src\pulp\solvers.py",line1363,in solver_CBC
pulp.solvers.PulpSolverError:Pulp:Error while trying to execute cbc.exe
```

line 188 is nothing but `prob.solve()`.
How can know what type of issue happen to solver?
I run same model with some dataset, it works.
But for some other dataset, it report this error.
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting one way to diagnose this problem is to write out the LP or MPS representation of the problem and to try and solve it with the solver outside of pulp.

use 'prob.writeLp("filename.lp")' to get the lp file

and install cbc separately.

Comment: Thank you, Stuart, I do nto have other solver on hand at the moment. But I would like to add more detail and my thoughts.

Comment: This a knapsack type problem with additional constraints. Each bag has label ["black","white","blackwhite"]. Each item has label ["black","white"]. If bag is labeled black or white, it can only hold the items with same color. If bag is labeled blackwhite, it can hold items with any color, but still only one color in one bag. The total number of items is 1500, and total number of bags is about 30. Item size is 100,000 to 3,000,000. Easy problem (bag size is 300,000 to 3,000,000) can be solved in 2 minutes using solverstudio. Hard problem (bag size 5,000.000 or above).

Comment: When hard problem is run, I set run time to 600 seconds. But a black window (cbc.exe) will appear and only a cursor is shown on the top left cornor of the window. I check cpu status, cpu is still running with cbc.exe, but at the end of 600 seconds, the black window is still their and no feasible or optimal solution is returned and optimization status is printed as expected as expected, even "infeasible" not printed. The hard knap problem should always have feasible solution (one item in one bag).

Comment: When I run the hard problem case and see the black window, I manually close the black window, I see the error message pop-up, as I posted in my question. The interesting thing is that after this issue, I test the small easier case which previously slovable in 2 minutes, now the case become non solvable and I got the same black window and error message just like the hard problem case.

Comment: Another findings is when I try hard problem every 3 to 5 times, solverstudio will be automatically removed from active add-on list, I have to manually add solverstudio add-on again.

Comment: Therefore, I have questions below:

Comment: 1. For the hard case in which bag size is large, I understand thre are too many feasible combinations solution, so optimal solution is hard to achieve, but why the solver can not provide a feasible solution, since feasible solution to knapsack problem is very easy to find, even zero item in bag is a feasible solution.

Comment: 2. After get trouble with hard problem, previously solved easy problem also get trouble. Does this means that solver information of previous hard problem is still in memmory, and late on act as initial solution to the new easy problem case? OR, trouble was made by manually stopping the cbc.exe from running?

Comment: I check the line 1362 and line 1363, but do not understand what is cbc.wait()                                                                         if cbc.wait() != 0:
            raise PulpSolverError("Pulp: Error while trying to execute " +  \
                                    self.path)

Comment: I did another test. case 1 and case 2 use same set of data for item sizes, say 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000, 100000, 200000, 300000,..., etc, in total, I have 1000 items. In case 1, I have 2 bags only, sizes of bags are 1000000, 2000000. This is easy case such that solver find optimal solution in seconds. In case 2, the only thing I did is I changed the size of bag 2 to 2222222. Then, trouble comes.

Comment: I did more test today, as a continuation of the very last comment I posted. Here I name them case 3 and case 4. In case 3, I change size of bag 2 to 222222, which is 10 time smaller than the counterpart in case 2. Same error occurs. In case 4, I change the size of bag 2 to 200000.22. Now I got the optimal solution. I also print the slack space of bag 2, in which I expext to see 0.22, but I got zero. Now I guess it is somehow related to rounding error. I will do more tests today.

Comment: Using cbc command line to import and solve the .lp generated from the hard problem case. The cbc solver works, and optimal solution found. It looks that the trouble is not related to cbc solver, but somehow related to pulp or solverstudio.

Comment: have you tried the solver studio option to write out the data files? then you can see if it is a problem running with normal cpython outside of solverstudio. I suspect you may be running into memory issues.

Comment: Stuart, I saved the .lp file of hard problem case, then import and solve problem using cbc command line. It works.

Comment: hi if you go view model window in solverstudio and change the language to Python(external) then solve the problem. If you then go to view the working files there will be all the file needed to run the problem in python externally.
With these files I can debug your problem